# Why is useEffect not being triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-component, use-state

I have a functional component that is supposed to be a running clock:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import { parseTime } from '../../Utils/utils'

const MainClock = (props) => {
    const [timeString, setTimeString] = useState(parseTime(new Date(), true));
    function tick(){
        console.log("TICK:" + timeString)
        setTimeString(parseTime(new Date(), true));
    };

    useEffect(()=>{console.log("rendered!");setTimeout(tick,500);},[timeString]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h5 className="center-align mainclock">{timeString}</h5>
        </div>        
    );
}
 
export default MainClock;
```

But for some reason it is only being rendered twice and the console output is:

```
rendered!
TICK:14:56:21
rendered!
TICK:14:56:22
```

Why isn't useeffect being called after the second render?

Any help is welcomed!

Edit: If it helps, this is `parseTime`:

```
const parseTime = (timeDate, withSeconds=false) =>{
    let time = timeDate.getHours()<10 ? `0${timeDate.getHours()}`:`${timeDate.getHours()}`;
    time+=":";
    time+= timeDate.getMinutes()<10 ? `0${timeDate.getMinutes()}`:`${timeDate.getMinutes()}`;
    if(withSeconds){
        time+=":";
        time+=timeDate.getSeconds()<10 ? `0${timeDate.getSeconds()}`:`${timeDate.getSeconds()}`;
    }
    return time;
}
```

Comment: whta's wrong here? i expect "rendered! TICK: ..." will be displayed per 500ms continuously.

Comment: @WilliamWang That's the problem. It's not displaying "rendered! TICK: ..."  continuously but only twice.

Comment: i checked and it works properly.

Comment: what does parseTime do?

Comment: just remove the parseTime and try

Comment: @WilliamWang `parseTime` returns a formatted hh:mm:ss string to a given Date object. I'm really not sure what is going on if you say it works properly for you. Does your console output continuously prints new "TICK!..."?

Comment: yes, without parseTime, i can see continuously prints

Comment: there is no problem.

Comment: can you attach your whole codebase into the jsfiddle so that i can see your wrong result?

Comment: ah, i found the error, just try to update the setTimeout interval not 500.

Comment: @WilliamWang I'm afraid not since it's private project. I've added parseTime since he's somehow the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is the use of `setTimeout` and the use of low delay, i.e `500ms` for the timeout. If you log the return value of `parseTime`, you will notice that between the two calls, it returns the same time string, so state never updates, leading to the component never re-rendering and hence `useEffect` never executes again to set another `setTimeout`.

#### Solution

Increase the timeout delay or check the return value of the `parseTime` function and if its the same as the one in the state, call this function again.

Moreover, its more appropriate to use `setInterval` here instead of `setTimeout` because `setInterval` will only need to be called once and it will call the `tick` function repeatedly until the interval is cancelled. If you use `setTimeout`, then you will need to call `setTimeout` again and again to schedule a new `tick` function call.

Comment: Wouldn't using `setInterval` create multiple stacking Intervals after every render? And why would I need to add tick to the dependency array if tick is updating a variable that's already in the dependency array?

Comment: I think setTimeout is correct rather than setInterval because setInterval always repeatedly call the tick function.

Comment: @MaorMagori share the code of `parseTime` and i will add more explanation of why the problems occurs and how it can be solved or share a reproducible example on codesandbox.

Comment: @Yousaf Added. Is parseTime what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As I indicated above, it is the problem of the short `setTimeout` timing value - `500ms`.
To make it work, you need to use `setInterval`

```
const MainClock = (props) => {
    const [timeString, setTimeString] = useState(parseTime(new Date(), true));
    function tick(){
        console.log("TICK:" + timeString)
        setTimeString(parseTime(new Date(), true));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(tick, 500);
    }, []);
    useEffect(()=>{console.log("rendered!");},[timeString]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h5 className="center-align mainclock">{timeString}</h5>
        </div>        
    );
}
```

Comment: You missed the dependency array of `useEffect` hook. You only want the `useEffect` to run only once and you should also use the cleanup function to cancel the `setInterval`.